# Header/Footer Icon usability

Tags: android, icons, header, footers

Consider the two screenshots shown below

[image: 2x2 icons (in "balance")]
[image: 2 + 3 icons (not "balanced")]

The context here is an "offers" mobile app with the icons serving the following functions

- Drop down "refine" results list (top left)
- Configure/Settings (top right)
- Search (bottom left)
- Offers on a map (bottom right)
- Shopping Basket (bottom right x 2 - if/when used)

The intent behind that last one is to ensure that the "basket" is accessible from the "main page" of the app with a single tap.

My own experience with using apps and websites is this

- I tend not to be attracted to apps that show too many header/footer icons (takes me too long to figure them out, to remember what they do
- It "looks" unattractive
- I make mistakes and tap on the wrong of 2 or more adjacent icons
- I tend to ignore all but one icon that appears in a group

I would like to know what take others here have on this

- Is this just a personal perception on my part?
- If not, what can be done to remedy the situation?

Comment: It might be mostly you, but I don't like icons with non-obvious meanings either.  The annoyance is mitigated, though, if they provide an explanatory hint when hovering.

Comment: Hover hints are of no use with mobile devices

Comment: Why not?  (I don't own one, so I don't know anything about them)

Comment: With a touch screen device there is nothing that can "hover" - no mouse pointer in sight.  So the only event that you can really hook into is the touch/tap event.

Comment: ah, okay, fairy nuff.  So no mitigation for handhelds, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a lot to solve with this design, even more than you refer to in your question.

> I tend not to be attracted to apps that show too many header/footer
>   icons (takes me too long to figure them out, to remember what they do

In general, you are right. Visual and functional overload is something that can affect usability a lot. Unfortunately, I think this is just the case here.

Not only the icons are spread around the interface, but they are also not hundred percent self-explanatory:

- Search icon - I believe it should refer to the content as much as possible, right now I would rather think it leads to another screen.
- Settings - why would I need to access it often? It is too exposed, and probably you will also need to put "About", and some other things somewhere as well, so I would suggest having a Menu icon.
- The marker icon is not self-explanatory. I would not know what it does.
- Shopping basket - it is not a good practice to hide an icon from the interface, instead I would add an "basket empty" state to it.
- The Refine icon does not refer to the content and looks like menu icon - a filter icon would really be a better choice here.
- Icons are placed a little bit too close to each other.
- I cannot see the app purpose described anywhere.

To make it more clear, I would do something like this:

[image]

This way:

- you can clearly tell one view from another (map vs. list)
- search and filtering use the recognisable icons and are directly related to the content
- shopping basket is always visible and clearly communicates if there is something inside of it (0 or no badge if empty).
- you have a menu where you can hide settings etc.